# Find the reduction $ - 23 \pmod {67} $

Tags: cryptography

I do not understand what the question is asking me to do?

Because if I do $-23 \pmod {67} = 44$? I am not sure if it is correct?

Comment: That *seems* like what they are asking but it is unclear. What exactly is the whole question.  If that is the whole question, then what according to *your* text book is the *precise* definition of "the reduction".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.

You added a multiple of $67$ such that the result is in $[0,67)$, which is what taking modulus means.

(Note that most programming languages have an *integer remainder* operation that works like modulus for positive arguments, but differs when there are negative numbers involved. That is not what you want here).

Comment: Hmm, out of curiosity, how common is the phrase "the reduction mod k"?  I somehow never run across it.  What is the terminology of $x \equiv a \mod k$ and $x \in [\lceil -\frac k2  \rceil, \lceil \frac k2 \rceil]$?

Comment: @fleablood: I'm not sure I have seen the phrase "reduction modulo $k$" about the result -- but I have certainly seen it describing the _process_ of finding that result.

Comment: Glad it's not just me then.  It seems me there are asking for 44, but I couldn't really tell be the question.

Answer (score 0):

$-23 \equiv 44 \pmod{67}$ iff  $67 |\left( 44 - (-23)\right)$ and $44 -(- 23) = 67$ so the numbers are indeed equivalent modulo $67$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind.  After googling I've found https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/755.pdf which seem to claim "the modular reduction" of $X \mod Y$ will by the remainder when $X$ is divided by $Y$.  And it is assumed that the remainder will be non-negative and less than $Y$.

So "the reduction" $-23 \mod 67$ will be the integer $k$ so that $-23 \equiv k \mod 67$ and $0 \le k < 67$.

That number, as you figured out, is $44$.

However the phrase "the reduction modulo Y" is not one that is familiar to me.  (Although the concept certainly is).

======

That is *probably* what they want.  But it is unclear what the mean be "the reduction".

Technically speaking $-23 \mod 67$ is not actually *equal* the integer $44$ but instead $-23$ and $44$ are *equivalent* to each other under the equivalence relation known as "modulo 67".  ($a$ is equivalent to $b$ modulo 67 if and only if $a = b + 67*k$ for some or any integer $k$.

So $44 \equiv -23 \mod 67$.  But there is no reason that $44$ is any *better* an answer than $-23$ or $111$ or $-90$ or $5538$ or ....

Oh...!

*Maybe*.  "The Reduction" means the equivalence class of $-23 \mod 67$.

An "equivalence class modulo 67" is the set of the all  integers so that all the elements of the set are equivalent to each other modulo $67$. The equivalence class of $-23 \mod 67$ will be all the integers, $k$ so that $k \equiv -23 \mod 67$.

This is written as $[-23] = \{z\in \mathbb Z| z \equiv -23 \mod 67\}$

$ = \{z \in \mathbb Z| z = -23 + 67*k; k \in \mathbb Z\}$

$=\{67*k - 23| k \in \mathbb Z\}$

$= \{..., -90, -23, 44, 111, 178, .....\}$[$*$]

Maybe *that* was the answer they wanted.

But you should go to the text and look up their definition of "the reduction".

=======

This is *technically* what is meant by $-23 \equiv 44 \mod 67$.  It *actually* means $-23$ and $44$ are both in the same equivalence class modulo $67$.